# Bindings not working in dynamically loaded component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm encountering a problem where if I dynamically load a component, none of the bindings in the template are working for me. As well as this the `ngOnInit` method is never triggered.

```
loadView() {
    this._dcl.loadAsRoot(Injected, null, this._injector).then(component => {
      console.info('Component loaded');
    })
  }
```

**Dynamically loaded component**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'

declare var $:any

@Component({
    selector: 'tester',
    template: `
      <h1>Dynamically loaded component</h1>
        <span>{{title}}</span>
    `
})

export class Injected implements OnInit {

    public title:string = "Some text"

    constructor(){} 

    ngOnInit() {
      console.info('Injected onInit');
    }

}
```

This is my first time using dynamically loaded components so I think may be attempting to implement it incorrectly.

Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2YGOFAxUgDmPx62Zjhbi?p=preview) demonstrating the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a known [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6223) with `loadAsRoot`. Your safest bet for now is to use either `loadNextToLocation` or `loadIntoLocation`.

Comment: @EricMartinez The component I'm trying to load is a modal dialog. The component I'm trying to load it from is inside an element with a `fixed` css style, so the dialog needs to be loaded pretty much as a first child of the `body` tag. Can I do this with `loadNextToLocation` or `loadIntoLocation` from within a deeply nested component?

Comment: I think you can fix that with pure CSS. If you set every position to 0 (top, left, right, bottom), position fixed and a high z-index value you can have a modal dialog wherever it is loaded into.

Comment: @EricMartinez I appreciate that but I don't really want to go messing around with CSS that's working just fine for me because of this bug. I've decided to pass the root `AppComponent` with forward ref and am now using `loadIntoLocation` with the `AppComponent`'s `ElementRef`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could add your solution as an answer, could be helpful for others

Comment: @EricMartinez Will do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Eric Martinez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4933038/eric-martinez) pointed out this is a known bug related to the use of `loadAsRoot`. The suggested workaround is to use `loadNextToLocation` or `loadIntoLocation`.

For me this was problematic as the component I was trying to dynamically load was a modal dialog from inside a component with `fixed` css positioning. I also wanted the ability to load the modal from any component and have it injected into the same position in the DOM regardless of what component it was dynamically loaded from.

My solution was to use `forwardRef` to inject my root `AppComponent` into the component which wants to dynamically load my modal.

```
constructor (
    .........
    .........
    private _dcl: DynamicComponentLoader,
    private _injector: Injector,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AppComponent)) appComponent) {

    this.appComponent = appComponent;
}
```

In my `AppComponent` I have a method which returns the app's `ElementRef`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <div #modalContainer></div>
    `,
    directives: [RouterOutlet]
})

export class AppComponent {

    constructor(public el:ElementRef) {}

    getElementRef():ElementRef {
        return this.el;
    }

}
```

Back in my other component (the one that I want to dynamically load the modal from) I can now call:

```
this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(ModalComponent, this.appComponent.getElementRef(), 'modalContainer').then(component => {
    console.log('Component loaded')
})
```

Perhaps this will help others with similar problems.

Comment: When I try it, the `loadIntoLocation` will attach the new component under the referenced tag (in your example, under `modalContainer` div. The problem is, when I call this twice, the component will be stacked with previously created component (latest component on top). What I want is like `loadAsRoot` behaviour where calling second time will replace previous component.

Do you manually clean the DOM before calling the `loadIntoLocation` second time?

Comment: Where do I find `@Inject` documentation? Is not available yet in angular 2 docs...

Comment: The child component did load but the ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit methods of the dynamically loaded component were called only when I do a mousemove. Did any of you face this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

No need to clean component instance from DOM.
use 'componentRef' from angular2/core package to create and dispose component instance.
use show() to load the modal component at desired location and  hide() to dispose the component instance before calling loadIntoLocation secondtime.

for eg:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <div #modalContainer></div>
 `,
  directives: [RouterOutlet]
})
export class AppComponent {
  private component:Promise<ComponentRef>;

  constructor(public el:ElementRef) {}

  getElementRef():ElementRef {
    return this.el;
  }

  show(){
    this.component = this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(ModalComponent,this.appComponent.getElementRef(), 'modalContainer').then(component => {console.log('Component loaded')})
  }

  hide(){
    this.component.then((componentRef:ComponentRef) => {
      componentRef.dispose();
      return componentRef;
    });
  }
}
```